# Difference between including javascript file directly in the main php page, or in a php subpage included in the main php page?

Tags: php, javascript, include

What is the difference between following two ways of including a javascript file:

1. Including javascript file directly in the main php page, as:

In *main.php* : `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="custom-script.js"></script>`

versus

2. Including javascript file in a php subpage, which further is included in the main php page, as:

In *main.php* : 
`<?php include('subpage.php'); ?>`

and In *subpage.php* : 
`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="custom-script.js"></script>`

Comment: Purely on the basis of the HTML result, there (in theory) shall be no difference between the two.

Comment: I have observed difference while including jquery-1.9.1.js for dropdown menu. When including it using above mentioned 2 ways, the dropdown functionality differs.

Comment: If you're calling other scripts in your `main.php` header and you include jQuery in your `sample.php` header, since there's a dependency it won't work properly.

Comment: Qantas, please find the edited version, I meant subpage.php and not sample.php
Probably, jQuery might be conflicting with some other script included on page; will recheck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only probable difference would be placement of the code which include the js file and hence the difference might be visible on final output HTML, if the functions are dependent in multiple js files.

Note: The placement of the code does matter in execution of the functions dependent on the js

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference in the end. Either way, the JS file is included by the client's browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to make any difference to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, unless using the sub page makes the `<script>` tag appear further down the page, in which case the browser won't execute it until it reaches that point.

As far as the browser is concerned, everything is "one page", it is not aware of any includes or divisions across PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference to the browser.

However for architecture style is better to have all JS inside separated php file that is included elsewhere.

This way you'll have much better control what you are including (one place control). If you want to add another script later on, you can just add it to subpage.php (better to name this something like javascript-includes-header.php) and you will have another script included on all pages. Same goes for removing a script or if you figure out that script include order is important.

Comment: Miha, thanks for pointing a better way of controlling multiple javascripts.

Comment: I am trying to find out the minor difference, if any, in the control flow process or anywhere, where it would have any effect.